# Convert a specific 2d array into 3d array

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to convert a 2D matrix like `A` into a 3D matrix. Every slice should be the same content like this:

```
A=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9];

for i=1:10
   B(:,:,i)=A
end
```

I need the same code without a loop, which decrease the speed of the program. In the original code A and i are rather big.

Comment: Have you tried `repmat`? `B=repmat(A,1,1,10)`.

Comment: Depending on what you want that repeated array for, you might not need it. See [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

Comment: Thats exactly what i searched for the whole time. Thanks :) I just started to code in malab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try

```
B = A(:,:, ones(1,10) );
```

Running a small [benchmark on ideone](https://ideone.com/mCIez1) shows this approach significantly faster than [`bsxfun`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27965228/1714410) or [`repmat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960921/convert-a-specific-2d-array-into-3d-array/27965256#comment44315423_27960921)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest and fastest way is using bsxfun, making use of the fact that it expands singleton dimensions:

```
A=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9];
B = bsxfun(@times,A,ones(3,3,10))
```

Here A is seen as a 3 x 3 x 1 matrix, and the third dimension is expanded to match the corresponding dimension in B (ie. 10).

Comment: why do you need to create the third argument of `bsxfun` as 3-by-3-by-10? it should be enough to use 1-by-1-by-10: `bsxfun(@times,A,ones(1,1,10))`

Comment: That's true. In the end it yields the same, but this makes it more clear what dimensions will be in the end. Yours might be a bit more efficient on huge arguments maybe.